# NameError: name 'statsmodels' is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to run a script in which I am doing a statistical test called Diebold Mariano. However, I am encountering a NameError related to statsmodels and cannot seem to figure out what to do to remedy this problem.

I thought the problem was related to importing so therefore I tried importing anything related to statsmodels but to no avail.

This is the part of the script causing errors.

```
for j in range(len(unique_firms)):

    for i in range(j+1,len(unique_firms)):

        firm1=unique_firms[i]
        firm2=unique_firms[j]

        ix_firm1_dft=dft.firm==firm1
        firm1_dft=dft.loc[ix_firm1_dft,['ticker','date','Forecast_error^2']]

        ix_firm2_dft=dft.firm==firm2
        firm2_dft=dft.loc[ix_firm2_dft,['ticker','date','Forecast_error^2']]

        firms_dft=pd.merge(firm1_dft, firm2_dft, how='inner', on=['ticker','date'])

        di=firms_dft['Forecast_error^2_x']-firms_dft['Forecast_error^2_y']

        dbar=di.mean()

        gammas=statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acovf(di, unbiased=True)

        h=int(np.floor(np.power(len(di),1/3)+1))
        denom=np.sqrt(gammas[0]+2*np.sum(gammas[1:h+1]))

        stat=dbar/denom
        pval=2*(1-stats.norm.cdf(np.abs(stat)))
        results[i,j]=stat
        pvals[i,j]=pval
        break
    break
```

This is the error I am getting, can anyone spot the problem?

```
NameError: name 'statsmodels' is not defined
```

Comment: did you install https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html ?

Comment: Please edit your question code to show the imports

Comment: In that code, `statsmodels` is indeed not defined anywhere.  Is it supposed to be an imported module, or a class, or what?  Where is it supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1):

You should do "import statsmodels.api" at the top of your python script. 
If you've already done that then you need to download latest statsmodel from :- https://pypi.org/project/statsmodels/#downloads

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels
```

And then in your .py file, put this on the top:

```
import statsmodels.api
```